# Why not all non-space and not * symbols copied? Why strcpy modifies source?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
    char q[100*1000+2];
    fgets(q,100*1000+2,stdin);//enter string
    int len=strlen(q)-1;
    char s[len];
    int i,j;
    for(i=j=0;q[i]!='\0';i++)
        if(q[i]!=' '&&q[i]!='\n'&&q[i]!='*')
        {s[j]=q[i];j++;}//remove all spaces, \n's and *
    len=j;//new length is length of s
    s[j]='\0';
    char copy[len];//copy s
    printf("s=%s\n",s);
    strcpy(copy,s);
    printf("s=%s\n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

For `x^125-228-7x^27` (0) program outputs as it should:

> s=x^125-228-7x^27
> s=x^125-228-7x^27

Then input is `+x^125-228-7x^274`(1):

> s=+x^125-228-7x^27
> s=+x^125-228-7x^27

But desired output is:

> s=+x^125-228-7x^274
> s=+x^125-228-7x^274

Or `+x^125-228-7x^27`(2):

> s=+x^125-228-7x^27
> s=

Even it should output:

> s=+x^125-228-7x^27
> s=+x^125-228-7x^27

If I replace `strcpy(copy,s)` to `memcpy(copy,s,len)` then (2) outputs

> s=+x^125-228-7x^27
> s=+x^125-228-7x^27

But with (1) it is still the same.

Comment: Kindly show your reseacrh / debugging effort so far. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: `len=j; s[j]='\0'; char copy[len];` Looks like `copy` doesn't have space for the string NUL terminator. Should be `char copy[len+1];`

Comment: If you'd format your code properly, you might find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ok. As I said I agree in general.

Comment: You seem to provide sample input and current output and desired output. Good. But I get lost in your explanations of what is what. Please [edit] and clarify. Mabye formatting is helpful to make things more obvious: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help I recommend to make triplets of texts, input, output now, output wanted. I think you have three examples. So try for three triplets.

Comment: Please fix according to @kaylum comment ( `char copy[len+1];` and `char s[len+1];`). In my experiments your program behaves much cleaner then. Afterwards we can discuss "Why strcpy modifies source?", which I do not really understand.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I still do not see desired output (though I think now that it was never there). Also you did not cleanup the size problem to focus on the "changes source" issue.

Comment: @Yunnosch I guess that "changes source" issue was not that it seemed to be. It was only size problem even if corruption happened then calling strcpy. So answer to my question will really be replace sizes. But now I have another question: why it worked correctly for e.g. (0)?

Comment: Please ask that new question as a separate dedicated question. I will turn the size recommendation into an answer here, in order to get this out of the list of unanswered questions. ( @kaylum I assume you agree, otherwise let me know. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As kaylum has already mentioned in comments and OP has already confirmed,
the solution is to make the arrays (plural is my contribution...) large enough to also include the terminator.

```
char s[len+1];
/* ...*/
char copy[len+1];
```